# UV Unwrapping is messed up because of a vertex leading into the wrong ending

Tags: uv, topology

my UV Unwrapping is messed up because of a vertex that leads into the wrong ending creating a triangular face (which is not the best thing, as I followed some tutorials saying it). (I think thats the problem)

So the top left line should lead into a new vertex and not the same as the top right one.

Thanks in advance!!

I try to showcase it in the following Images:

[image: Overview]
[image: Top View]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is your problem and you can fix it by selecting the stray edge in Edge mode and dissolving it by pressing <kbd>x</kbd> and by selecting Dissolve Edges.

[image: Dissolve edge]

Next use knife tool <kbd>k</kbd> and draw the missing edges.

[image: Knife tool start]

[image: Knife tool end]

Accept the cut by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Last select the newly created vertices and move them to better location by double pressing <kbd>g</kbd> and sliding them closer to the edge.

[image: Slide vertices]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Always wanted to know how to add edges if there's a missing one! Thanks for showing me a purpose for the knife tool!

For new people like me: Just press ENTER to make the new edges.

I also made the bottom line one the same level by selecting the vertices and pressing S+Y+0 in Bottom View.